# Plot a JSON file data using Plotly Library

Tags: javascript, python, graph, plotly, analysis

I am using plotly to plot different charts on my website. I just want to know how can I plot graphs using json file columns. The Json file have more than 5 columns and I want to plot a piecharts using two columns i.e. polarity(1,4,0) and Tweet Type(Positive, Negative, Neutral). i have provided the general code. how can I use this code to process the json.

```
var data = [{
  values: [19, 26, 55],
  labels: ['Residential', 'Non-Residential', 'Utility'],
  type: 'pie'
}];

var layout = {
  height: 400,
  width: 500
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: In python, there is no issue with, `plotly.plot(data)`

Comment: Can you add a sample JSON input?

Comment: @AChampion i am using this code in javascript

Comment: @MaximilianPeters like a 3 column csv converted to json

Comment: @ZerryMirza why do you have `python` tagged?

Comment: @AChampion because the we are getting and analyzing that data from Pytho.